# Want to create golden snitch wings sound effects

Tags: sound, design, effect

I want to know how to create the golden snitch wings sound effect (from Harry Potter's films). I've tried looking for fireworks spinners but I couldn't get the same effect of the films.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also interested in hearing some possible methods for creating this type of sound.

Answer (score 1):

Put some glass cleaner on a mirror and rub with a towel